# How to calculate probit marginal effects over groups with Stata

Tags: stata, probit, marginal-effect

How to properly calculate marginal effects of a probit model to capture marginal effect of one variable over a group. The setup is the following (simplified version):

**Data:**

```
healthy (1: eating healthy; 0: not eating healthy)
informed (1: yes; 0: no)
income (continuous variable as a control)
gender (1: female; 0: male)
```

**Research question: Does being informed affect women and men differently (e.g. men can be stubborn or more conservative and do not start eating healthy even after being informed)?**

Let's say that about 30% of female and about 10% of male eat healthy.

First I run Stata commands:

```
probit healthy informed income gender
margins, dydx(informed)
```

I can interpret the results and everything is OK.

1) However, if I want to check for for the main question and run:

```
probit healthy informed income gender
margins, dydx(informed) over(gender)
```

I get dubious results because I get 3 times higher (say 6% and 2%) marginal effects for female than for men (which corresponds to the ratio of female/male eating healthy - 30% vs 10%).

2) If I run the same regression without controlling for gender:

```
probit healthy informed income
margins, dydx(informed) over(gender)
```

I get quite similar marginal effects for women and men. But I am not sure if omitting gender as a control variable from the probit model is correct as I need to control for gender.

3) If I try to run the same thing in subsamples (female and male separately) such as:

```
probit healthy informed income if gender==1
margins, dydx(informed)

probit healthy informed income if gender==0
margins, dydx(informed)
```

I get once again nearly 3 times different marginal effects. But running it for subsamples seems wrong as the base probability rates are very different for genders and there are of course latent variables not included.

I've read Stata manual but couldn't figure out the right approach, new to Stata and probit. **All in all, I need to know if the marginal effects of being informed are statistically different for men and women** and would like to be able to find it with Stata.

I would be grateful if anyone could comment whether or which of my approaches is correct or how to properly do that.

Comment: Is this home work? Please clarify if your question is in regard of using stata or how to approach the research.

Comment: Real-world problem, not homework, my statistics knowledge is slightly outdated and lacking. Need to solve the problem which seems to be a classical probit case but I am probably making a mistake somewhere, don't know whether it concerns using Stata or how to approach the research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marginal effects are a bit trickier in nonlinear models and there are several options available. They correspond to evaluating the expression below at various sensible values of the covariates:

$AME=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial \Pr \left(
y_{i}=1|x_{1},...,x_{k}\right) }{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{1}{N}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\phi \left( \alpha +\beta _{1}x_{1i}+...+\beta
_{k}x_{ki}\right) \beta _{j},$

were $\phi()$ is the standard normal pdf.$^*$ People and disciplines have different notions of what is sensible. You want to take this a step further and compare two of these AMEs.

You want to compare the change in the probability of eating healthy when informed between men and women. One way to do this is to change the gender as if everyone was a man, but leave income unchanged, and calculate the average change when informed goes from 0 to 1. The set everyone to female, and leave income unchanged, and do that again. If these two averages are different, then men respond differently.

The code below calculates the change in the probability of a car being foreign when it is efficient versus not, and how that depends on whether it is expensive. I did it a couple of ways so that you can get the basic idea:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen efficient = mpg > 20
gen expensive = price > 6000
probit foreign i.efficient i.expensive c.headroom, nolog

/* Average Marginal Effects (AMEs) */
margins, dydx(efficient) at(expensive = (0 1)) // calculate the AMEs as if all cars were expensive or as if all were cheap with own values of headroom
margins expensive, dydx(efficient)             // same as above
margins r.expensive, dydx(efficient)           // compare the two average marginal effects by taking the difference
margins r.efficient#r.expensive                // same as above, but more cryptic

/* Calculate the AME for each type of car separately */
margins, dydx(efficient) over(expensive)
```

---

$^*$ This is actually not quite correct. This would be true for continuous variables. With binary variables, Stata is actually evaluating finite differences rather than derivatives since we used factor variable notation in the `probit`. FDs are the average of predicted probabilities with informed set to 1 minus predicted probability with informed set to zero. This makes more sense than contemplating infinitesimal changes in gender or information.

Comment: Given your answer, it seems that I should use your "Average Marginal Effects (AMEs)" example. But then I started to think that maybe using interaction term like `informed#gender` in the probit regression would be another option?

Comment: You could add that interaction, though probit has that built in already because of the link function. Google Data Colada #57 for the logit case, which carries over to the probit. The AME is sensible, but you could also do marginal effect at representative or mean/median/modal/base values.